# Rails Export multiple tables to csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

Hi I have a simple rails application that has two models Equipment_Types & Tasks

Each equipment type has many tasks. When I export to csv file I would like to export the name of the equipment type, the task name and the associated schedule. Basically every thing that is displayed on equipment_type/show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<div class="row">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="align-middle" rowspan="2">Equipment</th>
    <th class="align-middle" rowspan="2">Task</th>
    <th class="text-center" colspan="4">Frequency</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="text-center">M</th>
    <th class="text-center">Q</th>
    <th class="text-center">B</th>
    <th class="text-center">A</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <% if @taskcount > 3 %>
    <td class="text-center bottomtotop" rowspan="0"><%= link_to @equipment_type.name, edit_equipment_type_path(@equipment_type) %></td>
      <% else %>
      <td class="text-center" rowspan="0"><%= link_to @equipment_type.name, edit_equipment_type_path(@equipment_type) %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
    <% @equip_tasks.each do |task| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to task.name, task %></td>
      <td class="text-center"><%= if task.monthly then 'x' else ' ' end %></td>
      <td class="text-center"><%= if task.quarterly then 'x' else ' ' end %></td>
      <td class="text-center"><%= if task.sixmonthly then 'x' else ' ' end %></td>
      <td class="text-center"><%= if task.annually then 'x' else ' ' end %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapsenewline">

  </div>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm">
    <%= link_to 'Add Task', new_task_path(@equipment_type), class: 'btn btn-dark' %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm">
    <%= link_to 'Back', equipment_types_path, class: 'btn btn-dark' %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm">
    <button class="btn btn-dark" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsedownload" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
      Download
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm">
    <div class="collapse" id="collapsedownload">
      <div class="card card-body">
        <h3>Download File</h3>
        <%= link_to "csv", equipment_types_path(format: "csv"), class: 'btn btn-dark' %>
        <br>
        <%= link_to "pdf", equipment_types_path(format: "pdf"), class: 'btn btn-dark' %>
        <br>
        <%= link_to "word", equipment_types_path(format: "word"), class: 'btn btn-dark' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

equipment_type Model

```
class EquipmentType < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks

  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      EquipmentType.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end

  def self.to_csv
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      all.each do |equipmenttype|
        csv << equipmenttype.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

equipment_types Controller

```
class EquipmentTypesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_equipment_type, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_task, only: [:show]

  # GET /equipment_types
  # GET /equipment_types.json
  def index
    @equipment_types = EquipmentType.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @equipment_types.to_csv }
    end
  end


  # GET /equipment_types/1
  # GET /equipment_types/1.json
  def show
    @equipment_type = EquipmentType.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @tasks = Task.all
    @equip_tasks = @equipment_type.tasks.all
    @taskcount = @equip_tasks.count


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data text: @equip_tasks.to_csv }
    end
  end

  # GET /equipment_types/new
  def new
    @equipment_type = EquipmentType.new
  end

  # GET /equipment_types/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /equipment_types
  # POST /equipment_types.json
  def create
    @equipment_type = EquipmentType.new(equipment_type_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @equipment_type.save
        format.html { redirect_to @equipment_type, notice: 'Equipment type was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @equipment_type }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @equipment_type.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /equipment_types/1
  # PATCH/PUT /equipment_types/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @equipment_type.update(equipment_type_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @equipment_type, notice: 'Equipment type was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @equipment_type }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @equipment_type.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def import
    EquipmentType.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to equipment_type_path, notice: "Equipment Type Added Successfully"
  end

  # DELETE /equipment_types/1
  # DELETE /equipment_types/1.json
  def destroy
    @equipment_type.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to equipment_types_url, notice: 'Equipment type was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_equipment_type
      @equipment_type = EquipmentType.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_task
      @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def equipment_type_params
      params.require(:equipment_type).permit(:name, task: [])
    end
end
```

Task Model

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :equipment_type
end
```

Tasks Controller

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_task, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /tasks
  # GET /tasks.json
  def index
    @tasks = Task.all
  end

  # GET /tasks/1
  # GET /tasks/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /tasks/new
  def new
    @task = Task.new
  end

  # GET /tasks/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /tasks
  # POST /tasks.json
  def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /tasks/1
  # PATCH/PUT /tasks/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.update(task_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /tasks/1
  # DELETE /tasks/1.json
  def destroy
    @task.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tasks_url, notice: 'Task was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_task
      @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def task_params
      params.require(:task).permit(:name, :monthly, :quarterly, :sixmonthly, :annually, :equipment_type_id)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

You merely need to just append the attributes to the array.

Instead of,

`csv << equipmenttype.attributes.values_at(*column_names)`

Drop in this (or similar) (note: this is resource-intensive so you'll want to trim it down especially if you have lots of tasks)

```
def csv_attributes
  { 
    tasks: self.tasks.all.map(&:attributes).map(&:values),
    id: self.id  
  }
end
```

and then

`csv << equipmenttype.csv_attributes`

Comment: I get a 'undefined method `values' for []:Array Did you mean? values_at' am I missing something?